# Prettier not doing anything to a minified section of HTML?

Tags: prettier, prettier-vscode

Given the following code

`<ul><li><a href="https://www.google.com">Google</a></li></ul>`

When running prettier it keeps it one single line like that.. any way to break up each element to new lines?

Just something I've noticed when html elements are all basically on one line.